# The H.264 video codec disappeared from my settings in Export in Adobe Premiere 2022

Tags: adobe, edit, codec

I have Adobe Premiere 2022 and I updated Premiere from the 2020 version to the 2022 version. Now I don't see the H.264 video codec when I export.Is there any way to solve my problem?
I hope my problem can be solved. Thank for your help.